# Unable to update variable in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, printing

I am trying to print names of all .txt files from current folder in one line. I am using following script. However, it is not printing file names.

```
REF_SEQ=""
find . -name "*.txt" -maxdepth 1 -type f |
while read f;
do
    name=$(echo ${f}| xargs -I {} basename {} )
    REF_SEQ+="${name} "
done

echo "Full Sequence:  ${REF_SEQ}"
```

I have 3-4 .txt files in my current folder (A.txt, B.txt ...). I am expecting output as

> Full Sequence: A.txt B.txt ...

If I just use `find` command without assigning output to variable `RED_SEQ`, I do get desired output. This suggests that find command is working fine but somehow I am unable to assign it to variable. I tried various different assignment operators but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a variable in `bash`, you must use this syntax:

```
VAR="some stuff$VAR"
```

But, since you are using a pipe, the `while` loop is executed in a sub-shell, you variable is lost.

To correct this, you must have the syntax:

```
while read f
do
done <<< $(input)
```

So in your case:

```
REF_SEQ=""

while read f;
do
    name=$(echo ${f}| xargs -I {} basename {} )
    REF_SEQ="${REF_SEQ}${name} "
done <<< $(find . -name "*.txt" -maxdepth 1 -type f)

echo "Full Sequence:  ${REF_SEQ}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I have tried it already.

Comment: @DexOnWeb yes I answer too fast, corrected

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you use {} behind the pipe symbol. This is just valid in the -exec option of find, but not behind the pipe symbol.

You could try the following:

REF_SEQ=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -type f -printf "%f " | xargs)

This should produce the result you desire. The printf-directive %f outputs the basename of the file found and the xargs "transposes" the result.

Kind regards
Jürgen